# how to compare first word in a line with the last word using sed?

Tags: regex, unix, sed

lets say i have a file F1 that looks like this:

```
abc2 1 def2 3 abc2
123 zy
 cd eabc1d rq12345 cd
a a
a1a a1
```

I want to check if the first word in a line is equal to the last word, and if it is to do something....how do I write this regex to check if they are equal? :/

```
sed '/if_firstword_eq_lastword/do_something/'
```

ONLY SED PLEASEE

tnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use awk.

```
$ awk '$1==$NF' file
abc2 1 def2 3 abc2
 cd eabc1d rq12345 cd
a a
```

Through sed,

```
$ sed -n '/^ *\([^[:space:]]\+\)\b.* \1 *$/p' file
abc2 1 def2 3 abc2
 cd eabc1d rq12345 cd
a a
```

**Regex Explanation:**

`^` - Asserts that we re at the start.

`<space>*` - Matches zero or more space characters.

`\(...\)` - Called capturing group. Characters which are matched by the pattern present inside the capturing group will be stored inside the corresponding group index. We could refer these characters later through back-referencing.

`[^[:space:]]` matches a non-space character. `[^[:space:]]\+` matches one or more non-space characters. `\([^[:space:]]\+\)` now the matched characters are captured by the first capturing group.

`\b` called word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character. This forces the `[^[:space:]]\+` to match upto a space in the above example.

`.*` matches any character zero or more times.

`<space>\1`, `\1` here refers to the characters inside group index 1. `<space>\1` ensures that there must be a space exists before first character.

`<space>*` matches zero or more spaces.

`$` Asserts that we are at the end.

Note that the above sed may fail if the input contain non-word characters except space characters.

Comment: +1 for the awk answer, that's the way to go! I don't understand why this should be sed dependent, because it gets too complicated.

Comment: @AvinashRaj thats great man! can you please explain what the regex mean? i mean the different parts of it? i will mrk this as the correct answer :)

Comment: @nickshmick your professors teaching you something that's useless. You'd never use sed for this, it's a job for awk. The sed solution will fail if there's only 1 word on the line while the awk solution will not and the sed solution will only ever work with some seds while the awk solution will work with any awk (except old, broken awk of course).

Comment: @EdMorton i guess i can agree i will now use it this way but this is how it woks on school..