# regex for word repetition

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I need a regex for sed (only sed please) that help me to figure out if a certain word appears 3 times in a word so print this line...

lets say this is the file:

```
abc abc gh abc
abcabc abc
 ab ab cd ab xx ab
ababab cc ababab
abab abab cd abab
```

so the output is:

P1 F1

```
abc abc gh abc
 ab ab cd ab xx ab
abab abab cd abab
```

this is what im trying

```
sed -n '/\([^ ]\+\)[ ]+\1\1\1/p' $1
```

its not working...:/ what am i doing wrong??

it dosent matter if the word is in the beginning or not , and they dont need to appear as  sequence

Comment: It looks like you have a lot of homework... you already asked [how to compare first word in a line with the last word using sed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28318579/1983854), didn't you use the answer by Avinash to get a better attempt?

Comment: i dont understand what are you asking @fedorqui

Comment: Also repeated word need not be 1st word in a line right?

Comment: dosent have to be first @anubhava

Comment: `grep -E '(\b\w+\b)(.*?\b\1\b){2}' file` will get you what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `.*` inbetween `\1`

```
$ sed -n '/\b\([^ ]\+\)\b.*\b\1\b.*\b\1\b/p' file
abc abc gh abc
 ab ab cd ab xx ab
abab abab cd abab
```

I assume that your input contain only spaces and word characters.

Comment: I don't understand the \b syntax really...my teacher didnt explain about it and it looks like this make thigs shorter, can you maybe explain?

Comment: `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character . `A-Z` or `a-z` or `0-9` or `_` . Any character other than these characters are called non-word character.

Answer (score 0):

I know its asked for `sed`, but all system I have seen with `sed` also have `awk`, so here is an `awk`solution:

```
awk -F"[^[:alnum:]]" '{delete a;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++;for (i in a) if (a[i]>2) {print $0;next}}' file
abc abc gh abc
 ab ab cd ab xx ab
abab abab cd abab
```

This may be simpler to understand compare to a regex solution.

```
awk -F"[^[:alnum:]]" # Set field separator to anything other than alpha and numerics characters.
'{
delete a            # Delete array "a"
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) # Loop trough one by one word
    a[$i]++         # Store number of hits of word in array "a"
for (i in a)        # Loop trough the array "a"
    if (a[i]>2) {   # If one word is found more than two times:
        print $0    # Print the line
        next        # Skip to next line, so its not printed double if other word is found three times
    }
}' file             # Read the file
```